# How to exceed limitation of numpy.array() to convert list of array to an array of array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, limit

I have a list of arrays containing each one 16 int :

```
ListOfArray=[array([0,1,....,15]), array([0,1,....,15]), array([0,1,....,15]),....,array([0,1,....,15])]
```

I want to convert it to an array of array.

So I use :

```
ListOfArray=numpy.array(ListOfArray) 

or:
ListOfArray=numpy.asarray(ListOfArray)

or :
ArrayOfArray=numpy.asarray(ListOfArray)
```

Same result

If my list of arrays contained less than 17716 arrays I have the normal result :

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 ... 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
...
[0 1 1 ... 1 0 0]
[0 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 ... 0 0 1]]
```

But from 17716 arrays I have this :

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
 array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]) ...
 array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
 array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

It seems that there is a limit somewhere, why ?
Can we exceed it ?

Edit :

there is no problem with numpy.array.. It's wasn't desired to have an array containing 17 values. I converted wav frames into binary and then into string (of fifteen 0 and 1), which I add 0 before if it's a negative and 1 for positive, and then convert to a list and then an array.. I didn't expect a value of -32768 (-0b10000000000000000), believed that -32767 and 32767 (15 binaries digits) was the maximums. 
It's a pretty ugly code, i'm not proud, but if you have advice for a less patchworking code, here it is :

```
import numpy as np
import wave
import struct

f= wave.open('Test16PCM.wav','rb')

nf = f.getnframes()
frames=f.readframes(nf)

f.close()


L=[]

# extracting values samples
for i in range (0,((nf-1)*4)+1,4):

    L.append(  (struct.unpack('<h',frames[i:(i+2)])[0])  ) # only the left track


Lbin=[] # convert int values to string of binaries + 0 or 1 for negative or positive

for i in L:         
    a=str(bin(i))

    if a[0]=="-" :  # something like "-0b00101101"
        a=a[3:]

        while len(a)<16: # to have same length binary number (was 15 before correction)
            a='0'+a
        Lbin.append('0'+a)

    else :          # something like "0b00101101"
        a=a[2:] 

        while len(a)<16:
            a='0'+a

        Lbin.append('1'+a)


Lout=[]

for i in Lbin :
    temp=[]
    for j in i :
        temp.append(int(j))

    temp=np.array(temp)

    Lout.append(temp)


Lout=np.asarray(Lout)

print(Lout)
```

Comment: Please provide a full, runnable program that shows the problem.  I can't reproduce it with `ListOfArray=[np.arange(16)] * 20000; np.array(ListOfArray)`.

Comment: Numpy arrays are rectangular, and your subarrays are ragged: the last array you show has one more value than the ones before it.  If you explain what you want to happen, we can probably find an existing question which explains how to do it (e.g. padding the shorter rows to the length of the longer ones.)

Comment: Oh thank you ! So there is no problem with numpy.array.. It's wasn't desired to have an array containing 17 values. I converted wav frames into binary and then into string (of fifteen 0 and 1), which I add 0 before if it's a negative and 1 for positive, and then convert to a list and then an array.. I didn't expect a value of -32768 (-0b10000000000000000), believed that -32767 and 32767 (15 binaries digits) was the maximums.

Comment: For reference, numpy is automatically inferring `dtype=object` for the outer array when it detects ragged inputs, so it is using the inner arrays' plain `repr` rather than the fancy `str` logic.

Comment: if you already use numpy, maybe you should open your wave files with scipy.io.wavfile. it's faster and bullet-proof

Comment: Hi ! Ok thank you I will try scipy.io.wavfile ;)